# XCode 14 React Native project fails to run: Framework not found "EXAV"

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have recently update my macOS to Ventura and XCode to 14.0 and when I try to run the app from command line it works perfectly fine.
But when I try to build the project on XCode or archive it, I get this error at the very end of building process:

```
framework not found "EXAV"
```

My system configurations are:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.0
    CPU: (8) x64 Apple M1
    Memory: 16.96 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.18 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.13 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.10.24.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526
    Xcode: 14.0/14A309 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.16 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: ^7.0.3 => 7.0.3 
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```